# Extending Protocol Buffers in Java

Tags: java, protocols, protocol-buffers, extends, buffer

I'm having trouble accessing extended protocol buffer members.  Here is the scenario:

```
Message Foo {   optional int i = 1; }

message Bar {   extend Foo {
    optional int j = 10001;   } }
```

I don't have the Bar message within any of my other protos.  How can I get Bar.j in Java?  All examples I've found require a Bar within a message.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Extensions in Protocol Buffer don't work necessarily as you would expect, i.e. they don't match the Java inheritance mechanism.

For your problem, I have created the following `foobar.proto` file:

```
package test;

message Foo {
    optional int32 i = 1;
    extensions 10 to 99999;
}

message Bar {
    extend Foo {
        optional int32 j = 10001;
    }
}
```

It creates `Foobar.java`, containing the classes `Foobar.Bar` and `Foobar.Foo`.

And here is a simple JUnit test case accessing Bar.j:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import org.junit.Test;
import test.Foobar.Bar;
import test.Foobar.Foo;

public class TestFooBar {

    @Test
    public void testFooBar() {
        Foo foo = Foo.newBuilder().setI(123).setExtension(Bar.j, 456).build();
        assertEquals(Integer.valueOf(456), foo.getExtension(Bar.j));
    }
}
```

Hope that helps clarifying your problem!